# Match 2 columns in sheet 1 with the columns in sheet 2 and return the value of column 3 of the sheet 1

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets. sheet 1 contains col 1,col 2, col 3.

Similarly, sheet 2 has col 1, col 2, col 3. I wish to match a produce a output in this way:

```
if ((col 1(of sheet 1) == col 1 (of sheet 2)) && (col 2(of sheet 1) == col 2 (of sheet 2))),

then col 3(of sheet 1) = col 3 (of sheet 2)
```

(I hope I have made the question clear.)

Comment: I think the condition is clear but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Is col 3 of sheet 2 supposed to be changed to the value of col 3 of sheet 1, or dou you want it to have a separate matching value? Please elaborate.

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: col 3 of sheet 1 is just a blank column on which i am supposed to put the values from the column 3 of sheet 2 upon matching the above condition. @M.Schalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to SO - If you wonder why you have negative votes on your question, it's because people expect you to show what you have tried, not just request other to solve the problem. Next time try to show what you've tried this far.

The solution to your question:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$C$21,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$21=Sheet1!A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$21=Sheet1!B1),0),3)
```

1. enter in C1 of your Sheet1
2. adapt the ranges according to your requirements
3. it's an array formula, therefore enter with `ctrl + shift + enter`

Comment: i had no clue how to go about it

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`=IF(AND(A1=Sheet1!A1,Sheet2!B1=Sheet1!B1),Sheet1!C1,"No Match")`

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet2**

[image]

Comment: How do I compare 2 columns at the same time to produce the final result?

Comment: Import the formula in my answer in cell C1 sheet 2 and drag down

Comment: This solution is helpful if and only if I have the same element at the same index position. Right ?